# How to mask any parameter inside auto generated swagger java class

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, spring-aspects

How to mask any parameter in auto generated swagger java class ?
If manual getter setter class we can edit toString method but in autogenerated class it will generate swagger pojo class on each build so how to modify toString method which is autogenerated by swagger ?

Below is the code

**api.yml** ( which is generating POJO class through swagger)

```
InsuredDTO:
type: object
properties:
  id:
    type: integer
    format: int64
  name:
    type: string
  nric:
    type: string
```

**toString** Method inside auto generate POJO class

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.append("class InsuredDTO {\n");

  sb.append("    id: ").append(toIndentedString(id)).append("\n");
  sb.append("    name: ").append(toIndentedString(name)).append("\n");
  sb.append("    nric: ").append(toIndentedString(nric)).append("\n");
  sb.append("}");
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Adding some logs inside **LoggingAspect** class

```
log.debug("Enter: {}.{}() with argument[s] = {}", joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
            joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));
```

In this log `joinPoint.getArgs()` is having complete toString data with Id name and nric, here I want to display **masked nric** instead of direct **nric** value.

If it is not auto generated class then we can add something like below in toString method.

```
sb.append("nric: ").append("********").append("\n");
```

But in this case of auto generated class is there any way to mask any property only for logging purpose ?

I have tried with flag in yml file as below

```
properties:
  id:
    type: integer
    format: int64
  nric:
    type: string
    format: password
```

But this one also not formating the property in expected way.

Answer (score 0):

I add a similar requirement on an old project, I used an extension field (see [OpenAPI 3.0 Spec](https://swagger.io/specification/), end of file) like `x-nolog` and a custom code generator :

Example of schema :

```
User:
  type: object
  required:
  - name
  - password
  x-nolog:
  - password
  properties:
    name:
      type: string
    password:
      type: string
```

To create a custom code generator, you can see :

- http://docs.reprezen.com/codegen_custom_swagger_gentemplate/
- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/Building-your-own-Templates
- https://blog.arnoldgalovics.com/using-a-custom-template-for-swagger-codegen-with-gradle/